# Can't bind properties with @Bean and @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am reading configuration from properties file. Now I am having an error that **I think is related to sequence of initialization of spring bean**.

**If I do private Map name = new HashMap<>(); It can be successfully load from properties file.**

But now I am having **Could not bind properties to ServiceNameConfig**

I don't know why this happen and how to deal with it.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amazon.service")
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceNameConfig.class)
public class ServiceNameConfig {

   //If I do private Map<String, String> name = new HashMap<>(); It can be successfully load from properties file.
    private Map<String, String> name;

    @Bean(value = "serviceName")
    public Map<String, String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Map<String, String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

its usage;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serviceName")
Map<String, String> serviceNameMap;
```

Comment: I updated my answer here as an alternative suggestion without using `Map`, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your config class to be like this (simpler);

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amazon.service")
    public Map<String, String> serviceName() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

For `@ConfigurationProperties` injection, you'd need to supply an empty instance of the bean object. Check more about it on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

---

Or an alternative way, you can use a pojo class to handle the configuration. For example;

You have properties like;

```
amazon:
  service:
    valueA: 1
    valueB: 2
    details:
      valueC: 3
      valueD: 10
```

and you can use a pojo like the following;

```
class Pojo {

    private Integer valueA;
    private Integer valueB;
    private Pojo2 details;

    // getter,setters

    public static class Pojo2 {

        private Integer valueC;
        private Integer valueD;

        // getter,setters
    }
}
```

and use it in the config class like;

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amazon.service")
    public Pojo serviceName() {
        return new Pojo();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I junit test the nested Pojo2 class with ApplicationRunner? ApplicationRunner only instantiates the outer class in the context.